# Scrollbar on getting the screen bigger

Tags: css, html, scrollbar

I have some divs and I want that when I get the screen bigger(CTRL +) the scrollbar appear on the bottom of the page and the divs STAYS inline block, I have the code here(http://fiddle.jshell.net/JNzFp/) and as you can see when you get the screen bigger scrollbar appears under the divs and I want it to display on the bottom of the full screen.

Comment: Please share some more information, share the css and html you are using here only?

Comment: You can see the code in the website.. http://fiddle.jshell.net/JNzFp/

Comment: With `position:fixed` on the menu you will unfortunately not get the page to scroll horizontally when the menu gets wider than the viewport. And you have to change to `overflow:visible;` if you don't want a scroll bar to apear on the menu as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option is just to remove `white-space: nowrap;` so that your menu will naturally wrap when zooomed in, as a responsive design would do.

Comment: AS I said, I want it to stay in the SAME LINE(near each other)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code for creating menu:

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
<div class="main-navigation">
    <div id="clubbmenu" class="menu-top-meniu-container">
        <ul id="menu-top-meniu" class="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Description</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Shippings and Payments</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Seller Information</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Feedback</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>  
</div><!-- end .main-navigation -->
```

**CSS**

```
#main {
    padding-top: 10px;
    height: 48px;
    clear: both;
    width: 981px;
    margin: 0px auto 8px auto;
}

.main-navigation {
    width: 975px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    zoom: 1;
}

#clubbmenu {
    zoom: 1;
}

#clubbmenu > ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

#clubbmenu > ul > li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 7px;
    padding: 0;
}

#clubbmenu > ul > li > a {
   text-transform: uppercase;
   text-decoration: none;
   display: block;
   padding: 8px 30px 8px 30px;
   font-size: 17px;
}
```

Set margin, padding according to your needs.

Comment: Explore, Learn, Adapt, Evolve.